# JWT Token auth using python requests for DockerHub

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, dockerhub

I found out that editing a `full_description` of a DockerHub repository can be done via a [JavaScript API](https://github.com/RyanTheAllmighty/Docker-Hub-API), and figured this would be a fun excuse to learn the `requests` package for python.  The JavaScript API definitely works, e.g. using [this simple docker image](https://github.com/SISheogorath/readme-to-dockerhub/blob/master/index.js).

The JS API basically does

1. [Send a `POST` request](https://github.com/RyanTheAllmighty/Docker-Hub-API/blob/1bb380e4d5cdcc22f5ca88d7427403f691abf8f7/src/api.js#L49) to `https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login` with the username and password.  The server responds with a `token`.
2. [Send a `PATCH` request](https://github.com/RyanTheAllmighty/Docker-Hub-API/blob/1bb380e4d5cdcc22f5ca88d7427403f691abf8f7/src/api.js#L880) to the specific `https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/{user or org}/{repo}`, making sure the header has `Authorization: JWT {token}`, and in this case with content body of `{"full_description":"...value..."}`.

What is troubling is that the `PATCH` request on the python side gets a 200 response back from the server (if you intentionally set a bad auth token, you get denied as expected).  But it's response actually contains the current information (not the patched info).

The only "discoveries" I've made:

- If you add the [debug logging stuff](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#api-changes), there's a 301.  But this is the same URL for the javascript side, so it doesn't matter?

  ```
  send: b'{"full_description": "TEST"}'
  reply: 'HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY\r\n'
  ```
- <strike>The token received by doing a `POST` in `requests` is the same as if I `GET` to `auth.docker.io` as decribed in [**Getting a Bearer Token** section here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/jwt/).  **Notably**, I didn't specify a password (just did `curl -X GET ...`).</strike> This is not true.  They are different, I don't know how I thought they were the same.

This second one makes me feel like I'm missing a step.  Like I need to decode the token or something?  I don't know what else to make of this, especially the `200` response from the `PATCH` despite no changes.

The code:

```
import json
from textwrap import indent
import requests


if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = "<< SET THIS VALUE >>"
    password = "<< SET THIS VALUE >>"
    repo = "<< SET THIS VALUE >>"

    base_url = "https://hub.docker.com/v2"
    login_url = f"{base_url}/users/login"
    repo_url = f"{base_url}/repositories/{username}/{repo}"

    # NOTE: if I use a `with requests.Session()`, then I'll get
    # CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect
    # Because I think that csrftoken is only valid for login page (?)
    # Get login token and create authorization header
    print("==> Logging into DockerHub")
    tok_req = requests.post(login_url, json={"username": username, "password": password})
    token = tok_req.json()["token"]
    headers = {"Authorization": f"JWT {token}"}

    print(f"==> Sending PATCH request to {repo_url}")
    payload = {"full_description": "TEST"}
    patch_req = requests.patch(repo_url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    print(f"    Response (status code: {patch_req.status_code}):")
    print(indent(json.dumps(patch_req.json(), indent=2), "    "))
```

Comment: Can you check the type of `token`? I'm not sure if I remember correctly but in python sometimes stuff gets converted to bytestring and all of a sudden it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good thought, I hadn't considered that.  The `type(token)` is `str`, but I'll dig in on that a little more.  It could be that there's some knobs I can turn on how `requests` or maybe `urllib3` actually decodes the transmitted response.

Comment: Can you also confirm that the token you get is an actual JWT? The `Getting a bearer token` link you posted seems to tell that you need to encode the reply to get a functional JWT but I'm not sure without knowing what the reply on the request is.

Comment: Edited, I have no idea why I thought they were the same...they aren't.  `Can you also confirm that the token you get is an actual JWT?`  I have no idea, but I'm afraid to post the response that comes from giving my username / password ;)  I'm playing with the [`jwt` module](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), I think I either need to encode or decode something like you say.  I wish I could help you help me, but I don't know what I don't know x0  I appreciate you offering suggestions though, I'll keep grinding :)

Comment: Please could you clarify the problem. I don't understand what you think is unexpected about the way the PATCH request/response behaves. You mention "200 response from the PATCH despite no changes," but to me, that is expected. If I sent an identical PATCH request multiple times I would expect to get back `200 OK` each time.

Comment: I don't know much about how any of this stuff works. I was trying to perform the same thing in Python that the js code uses. The `PATCH` doesn't actually go through (description doesn't change, unlike the js version). So I want a non-2XX response since my `PATCH` is getting rejected. But it sounds like you're saying even if the `PATCH` is rejected, `200` is the expected responded? (I fully admit my web-novice...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the `JWT {token}` auth was valid the entire time.  Apparently, you need a `/` at the end of the URL.  Without it, nothing happens.  LOL!

```py
# ----------------------------------------------------V
repo_url = f"{base_url}/repositories/{username}/{repo}/"
```

As expected, the `PATCH` then responds with the updated description, not the old description.  WOOOOT!

Important note: this is working for me as of January 15th 2020, but in my quest I came across [this dockerhub issue](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1927) that seems to indicate that if you have 2FA enabled on your account, you can no longer edit the `description` using a `PATCH` request.  I don't have 2FA on my account, so I can (apparently).  It's unclear what the future of that will be.

Related note: the JWT token has remained the same the entire time, so for any web novices like myself, don't share those ;)

Answer (score 1):

Additional information related to your CSRF problem when using requests.Session():

It seems that Docker Hub is not recognizing `csrftoken`  named header/cookie (default name of the coming cookie), when making requests in this case.
Instead, when using header `X-CSRFToken` on the following requests, CSRF is identified as valid. 
Maybe reason is [cookie-to-header token pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-header_token)

Once updating session header with cookie of login response

`s.headers.update({"X-CSRFToken": s.cookies.get("csrftoken")})`

There is no need to set JWT token manually anymore for further requests - token works as cookie already.

Sorry, no enough privileges to just comment, but I think this is relevant enough.

Comment: awesome, thanks for sharing (and welcome to SO)! :)

Comment: Thank you for letting me make this comment!